# Infimum of a subgroup $= 0$ implies...?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $H$ be a subgroup of $\Bbb{R}$ (under addition).

Assume that for all $b \in \Bbb{R}_{>0}$, there exists $h \in H$ such that $0 < h < b$. Show that for all $x$, $y \in \Bbb{R}$ such that $x < y$, there is $h \in H$ such that $x < h < y$.

---

This problem even stumped my professor. I know that the problem is basically implying that $\inf\{h \in H\}=0$ and using it to prove the following inequality, and I understand it conceptually, but I'm not sure how to prove it using just arbitrary $x$, $y$, and $h$. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Right now, I'm not seeing any mention of groups or the like.  Do you mean for $H$ to be a subgroup of $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: Do you know that this is true? It seems like $H=(0,1)$ and $x=2,y=3$ will contradict the statement.

Comment: Surely you made a mistake in asking the question.  Let $H = (0,1)$ and $x = 9 gazillion$ and $y = 10 gazillion$.  $x < h < y => h > 9 gazillion > 1$. $h \not \in H$.

Comment: Yes sorry! I meant subgroup...

Comment: You need an operation to have a subgroup. This still isn't true if it's $\mathbb R$ under multiplication, for example.

Comment: I think you meant $x < x + h < y$.  Which is trivial by taking $0<h<y-x$.  So... I have no idea what the actual question was nor why in stumped your professor.

Comment: A group under multiplication or addition?

Comment: This is exactly how the question was written... would altering any part of the question make it true?

Comment: Yes, I think for $(\mathbb R,+$) it will be true.

Comment: Just emailed my professor. We are allowed to assume that R is an additive group. I'll edit the problem.

Comment: Then just pick the $h$ where $0 < h < (x-y)$ and add it to itself (closure of H) until you're in the right spot. Since the spacing of $h\mathbb Z$ will be finer than the distance between $x$ and $y$ you have to land in there eventually. (this looks approximately the same as Noah's answer below).

Comment: What do you mean adding it to itself? Double the inequality?

Comment: By adding h to itself CC means $h + h + h + h.....$.  If $h \in H$ then $n*h = h+h+h+ h+ h.... \in H$ for any integer n.  By archimedian prinicipal of real numbers there exists an integer m such that $m*h \le x$ but $(m + 1)h > x$.    If $0< h < y-x$ then $x<(m + 1)h < y$ and (m+1)*h $\in H$.

Answer (score 1):

HINT: For $h\in H$, let $Mult(h)=\{z\cdot h: z\in\mathbb{Z}\}$ be the set of multiples of $h$. For $x\in\mathbb{R}$ and $h\in H$, let

- $Small_h(x)$ be the greatest $k\in Mult(h)$ such that $k\le x$; and
- $Big_h(x)$ be the least $k\in Mult(h)$ such that $k>x$.

Note that $Big_h(x)=Small_h(x)+h$.

Suppose $Big_h(x)\not\in (x, y)$. What can you say about $h$ in terms of $y-x$?

Answer (score 1):

Under multiplication:

Not true.  Let H = {$2^n| n \in \mathbb Z$}.  For any $b > 0$ there is a $1/2^n$ such that $0 < 1/2^n < b$, but there is no $2^n in [5, 7]$.

Under addition:

Let $0 < h < y-x$.  By Archimedian principle find $n \in \mathbb Z$ such that $nh \le x$ but $(n + 1)h > x$.  Then $(n + 1)h = nh + h < x + (y-x) = y$ so $x < (n+1)h < y$.  $(n+1)h \in H$.

Answer (score 1):

The question has already been answered by fleablood and Noah Schweber, so I want to remark on why their solution looks the way it does.

Maybe you think the solution looks inelegant. You wonder, why can't we solve the problem using just a few algebraic tricks, like we did so often in high school? If we're really clever, maybe we can add one inequality to another inequality in such a way that the answer pops right out? Something like:

$$\begin{eqnarray}
0&<&h&<&y-x \\
0&<&\frac{h}{2}&<&\frac{y-x}{2} \\
&&\vdots&& \\
&&&&\mathrm{(insert\; miracle)} \\
&&\vdots&& \\ x&<&3h&<&y
\end{eqnarray}$$

Nope, and here's why.

Consider the following generalization of your problem. We will replace the real numbers with a generic group $R$. For the question to mean roughly the same thing as before, $R$ should be a linearly ordered Abelian group. Then the straightforward generalization reads like this:

- Let $(R,+,0,<)$ be a linearly ordered Abelian group. Let $H$ be a subgroup of $R$ (under $+$). Assume that for all $b \in R_{>0}$, there exists $h \in H$ such that $0 < h < b$. Is it true that for all $x$, $y \in R$ such that $x < y$, there is $h \in H$ such that $x < h < y$?

This time the answer is no! Here's a simple counterexample: Let $R=\mathbb Z\times\mathbb Q$, the lexicographic product of the integers with the rational numbers. (This just means that elements of $R$ are compared in the dictionary order.) Let $H=\{0\}\times\mathbb Q$, the set of pairs whose first coordinate is zero. Then $H$ satisfies the hypotheses of the question: For $b=(b_1,b_2)\in R_{>0}$, if $b_1=0$ then take $h=(0,b_2/2)$ and if $b_1>0$ then take $h=(0,1)$. Now let $x=(1,0)$ and $y=(1,1)$. Then $H$ does not have any element between $x$ and $y$; indeed $H<x$ altogether!

The existence of this counterexample means that we cannot answer the original question using just the laws of ordered groups! We *need* to bring in some additional information about the real numbers $\mathbb R$.

Now, look at the answers again. They use the fact that $\mathbb R$ is *not* just any old ordered group; it is an *Archimedean* ordered group. The proof goes through just the same for any Archimedean group, which is strong evidence that the Archimedean property is the *right* property to call upon.